# How to extract multiple values using xpath extractor and use it in beanshell post processor?

Tags: csv, xpath, soap, jmeter

I'm using xpath extractor to extract particular values from soap response and writing into the csv file using Beanshell post processor but here,i'm facing problem like i need multiple values from soap response.

Please any one provide how to use xpath extractor to extract multiple values from soap response and save it in separate variables and write into csv file.

For Example:

Soap response:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <soap:Body>
      <ValidateCardResponse xmlns="http://service.clp.eks.com">
         <out>
            <birthDate xmlns="http://wsform.clp.eks.com">01-01-73</birthDate>
            <cardno xmlns="http://wsform.clp.eks.com">23016077</cardno>
            <customerName xmlns="http://wsform.clp.eks.com">gopi</customerName>
            <flag xmlns="http://wsform.clp.eks.com">TRUE@19@FALSE</flag>
            <memberLevel xsi:nil="true" xmlns="http://wsform.clp.eks.com"/>
            <points xmlns="http://wsform.clp.eks.com">43292.65</points>
            <reason xmlns="http://wsform.clp.eks.com">SUCCESS</reason>
         </out>
      </ValidateCardResponse>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

I need two parameters to save it in csv file for each record i.e points and reason because in-case card is invalid then reason will come as card is invalid.
Please provide how to do this one ,if i'm using two xpath extractors then i'm getting error message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Add [XPath Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#XPath_Extractor) as a child of the request which returns above XML
2. Configure it as follows:

   - Reference Name: anything meaningful, i.e. `myVar`
   - XPath query: `//points/text() | //reason/text()`

It will generate the following JMeter Variables:

```
myVar=43292.65
myVar_1=43292.65
myVar_2=SUCCESS
myVar_matchNr=2
```

3. Add [JSR223 PostProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) **after** the XPath Extractor
4. Put the following code into "Script" area:

   ```
   new File('myFile.csv') << vars.get('myVar_1') << ',' << vars.get('myVar_2') << System.getProperty('line.separator')
   ```

See [Using the XPath Extractor in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-xpath-extractor-jmeter-0) article for more details on extracting data from XML, XHTML and HTML responses using XPath language.

---

Be aware that it is better to use [Sample Variables](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/listeners.html#sample_variables) property in order to store JMeter Variables into a file. If it doesn't suit you for any reason consider using [JSR223 Elements](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223) instead of Beanshell as Beanshell interpreter has known performance problems when it comes to high loads.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer and it is working fine but DEFAULT VALUE is not printing in file displaying null incase value is not present in soap response.